# Find gradient of $\operatorname{tr} \left( B^{T}X^{T}A^{T}CXD \right)$

Tags: derivatives, inner-products, matrix-calculus, trace

I need to find the derivative wrt ${X}$ of:

$$ f({X}) = \operatorname{tr}( B^{T}X^{T}A^{T}CXD )$$

To make this simpler, I let $E = A^{T}C$, then I have:

$$ f({X}) = \operatorname{tr}( B^{T}X^{T}EXD ) = \operatorname{tr}( DB^{T}X^{T}EX )$$

We can rewrite this using the Frobenius inner product:

$$ f({X}) = XBD^{T}:EX$$

So we can calculate the differential easily now:

$$ df = (dX)BD^{T}:EdX$$

Unfortunately this is where I am stuck.

---

Perhaps we can rewrite this as:

$$ df = BD^{T}:(dX)^{T} E dX$$

But how do we isolate the dX value?

---

Edits:

I tried: $(dX)^{T} E dX = \operatorname{tr}( dXdX^{T}E) = \operatorname{tr}( EdXdX^{T}) $ but that isn't getting me anywhere either...

Comment: What are the dimensions of $A,\,B,\,C,\,D,\,X$?

Comment: @J.G. Such that they work in the original formulation. However they are all matrices.

Comment: Have you considered the usual limit definition?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri No I have not. Perhaps I will try that as well, but I think this can be solved using differentials. I just don't know how...am I missing a step?

Comment: I'm not well versed in differentials. I usually deal with these problems by considering $(X+H)$, etc.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Okay I will try to work it out that way too.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Neither am I haha I am just learning this now to try and solve some problems I am encountering.

Comment: You cannot differentiate both X's in one go, i.e.  $d(xx)=(dx\,x+x\,dx)\ne(dx\,dx)$

Comment: @greg So then $tr(B^{T}X^{T}EXD) \rightarrow tr(B^{T}(dX^{T})EXD) + tr(B^{T}X^{T}E(dX)D) $?

Comment: Yes. It's the same thing that Joriki's saying in his answer.

Comment: There's no reason for $C$ to be there, as it could be absorbed by $A$. And $D$ could be absorbed by $B$. Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2777894/339790).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Almost, but regardless that was very helpful. Thank you for your kind assistance. I was hoping to do it using differentials. I am learning alot about this subject -- enough to start making some real progress on my engineering problems. I just hope my model is reasonable now haha but that is a different story!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get two terms, one for each factor involving $X$. You can manipulate the trace for each one separately. Apparently you know that the derivative of $\operatorname{tr}Y^\top X$ is $Y$. For the first term, apply this to $\operatorname{tr}(DB^\top X^\top EX)$ to obtain $E^\top X BD^\top$. For the second term, use the invariance of the trace under cyclic permutation and under transposition to write $\operatorname{tr}(DB^\top X^\top EX)=\operatorname{tr}(X^\top EXDB^\top)=\operatorname{tr}(BD^\top X^\top E^\top X)$ and obtain the second term $EXDB^\top$. Thus the derivative is $E^\top X BD^\top+EXDB^\top$.

Comment: Ah okay so I missed the two term part...I am not quite sure how to get that out yet though. Ie where the two terms come from.

Comment: @the_src_dude: It's basically the product rule. If you take the derivative of $d\cdot b\cdot x\cdot e\cdot x$ with respect to $x$ for scalars, you likewise get $d\cdot b\cdot e\cdot x+d\cdot b\cdot x\cdot e$. The only difference is that you need to manipulate the trace in two different ways to see what exactly the resulting terms should be.